# How can I change the target of the action on a button - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class CustomAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView
{
    let selectedLabel:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 125))
    let Button:UIButton = UIButton.init(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 38))

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(false, animated: animated)

    if(selected)
    {
        selectedLabel.text = annotation!.title!
        selectedLabel.center.x = 0.5 * self.frame.size.width
        selectedLabel.center.y = -0.5 * selectedLabel.frame.height

        self.addSubview(selectedLabel)

        Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        Button.setTitle("Press", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        //the code below here //
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let Map = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Map")
            Button.addTarget(Map, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        //self.view.addSubview(button)
        Button.center.x = 0.5 * self.frame.size.width + 10
        Button.center.y = selectedLabel.center.y
        self.addSubview(Button)

    }
    else
    {
        selectedLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

//This in Map.swift

```
    func buttonAction () {
        print("button pressed")
    }
}
```

Instead of using Button.addTarget(self...
As i'm coding in a custom class.
How do I get it to run the action?
I've set the names also for the storyboard as Main on the right panel and same with the Map.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` is released after go out the `setSelected` method. You should handle the `Map` by something(property, global variable, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one possible solution to this would be to add a tap gesture recognizer to the button which can be done in code like this:

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("actionTap:"))
    tap.delegate = self
    Button.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then you could let the view controller conform to the class of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

Also, create a function that will do what you want the button to do when tapped, and name it "actionTap" like this:

```
    func actionTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // Implement what you want the button to do here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your CustomAnnotationView class add a block:

> var tapProccess:(()->())?

in your action func

```
func buttonAction () {
    self.tapProccess?()
}
```

And implement it:

```
    let customAnno = CustomAnnotationView()
    customAnno.tapProccess = {()->() in
        // do some thing
    }
```